# Sending JSON file using relative path with curl

Tags: json, rest, curl

I have a JSON file called `people.json`:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Adam"
    }, 
    {
        "name": "Eve"
    }
]
```

I'm trying to send this data using a POST request with `curl`, from the project's root directory:

```
curl --request POST \
     --header 'Content-Type: application/json' 'Accept: application/json' \
     --data-binary @src/test/java/com/spring/app/people.json \
     http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/person -v -s
```

I keep getting the "Bad Request" error:

```
* Closing connection -1
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> POST /api/v1/person HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.74.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 80
> 
* upload completely sent off: 80 out of 80 bytes
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 400 
< Content-Type: application/json
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Sat, 12 Dec 2020 03:56:38 GMT
< Connection: close
< 
* Closing connection 0
{"timestamp":"2020-12-12T03:56:38.822+00:00","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"","path":"/api/v1/person"}%
```

I've already had a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16621248/13055097), but still get the same error.
I've also installed homebrew `curl`, but even using that doesn't resolve the error.

I would appreciate any help.